# How to find the indices of columns that are not entirely zeros of a sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a large sparse array (Python csr). How can I find the indices of columns that are not entirely zeros?

For example, if the matrix looks like `s` constructed below

```
In [13]: import  scipy.sparse as sparse

In [14]: s=sparse.dok_matrix((2,4))

In [15]: s[0,0]=8; s[0,3]=9

In [16]:  print (s.toarray())
[[8. 0. 0. 9.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The nonzero indices for the matrix `s` will be [0,3].

Comment: can you provide a constructor for an example?

Comment: Thanks for the useful suggestion. A constructor is now provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix                                                                     
                                                                                                        
A = csr_matrix([[1,2,0],[0,0,3],[4,0,5]])                                                               
                                                                                                        
nonzero_indices = A.nonzero()
```

`nonzero()` will return a tuple of two lists containing the indices you're looking for. For example:

```
for i,_ in enumerate(nonzero_indices[0]):                                                               
    print(nonzero_indices[0][i], nonzero_indices[1][i])
```

will give

```
0 0
0 1
1 2
2 0
2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use:

```
import numpy as np
np.nonzero((s!=0).sum(0))[1]
```

output: `[0, 3]`

Comment: It works on my small example. I am slightly concerned about performance, since you are doing a sum here. Can you avoid that?

Comment: I'm not a specialist of sparse matrices, maybe give the answer of @JustLearning a try on your large example and see for yourself ;)

Answer (score 2):

While the `sum(0)` solution is correct, it seems to me it does a bit of extra work. What you need is easy to do in csc format.

```py
import numpy as np
t = s.tocsc()
np.nonzero(t.indptr[:-1] != p.indptr[1:])[0]
```

If you need to process a large matrix this might work better, though I didn't test it.

### Explanation

The `t.indptr` stores indices to `t.indices` and `t.data` for each column in CSC format (row in CSR). The indices for row `i` are stored in `t.indices[t.indptr[i]:t.indptr[i+1]`: `t.indptr[i]` is the starting position and `t.indptr[i+1]` is the ending position. For your example, in CSC format `t.indptr = [0, 1, 1, 1, 2]`. If `t.indptr[i] == t.indptr[i+1]` then you have no elements corresponding to column (row) `i`.

The conversion to CSC is the most costly operation here and it is linear in number of non-zero elements.